# Shorten and simply conditional statement?

Tags: c#

I have this statement (which works):

```
x => x is View v && (x as View).IsTemplate
```

where the IsTemplate property only exists on the derived type View

I would like to shorten it to:

```
x => x is View v & v.IsTemplate
```

But I cant, I get the error "use of unassigned local variable".
Eventhough intellisense gives me the IsTemplate property.
Is this impossible, or did I miss something in the syntax? It looks much nicer and I cant see any logic issues with it.

Comment: How about  `x => (x as View)?.IsTemplate ?? false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are using `&` operator in the second code, the right side will be evaluated even though the left operand evaluates to `false`. You should change it to `&&`

```
x => x is View v && v.IsTemplate
```

Comment: Still needs either a direct or type-safe cast, `IsTemplate` is unlikely to be a property on the/a base object

Comment: @phuzi why though? both side returns boolean.

Comment: Because `v` is unlikely to have the `IsTemplate` property because it'll be a base object.

Comment: That's not unlikely. if View has IsTemplate and the v is View, then why it wouldn't have IsTemplate property ?

Comment: Damnit, I feel ashamed. Too easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are before C#7, otherwise use Selman's answer.

```
x => (x as View)?.IsTemplate ?? false;
```

Comment: Beat my comment by 15 seconds :op